# Computing the Galois Group and intermediate fields for the extension $\mathbb{Q}(3^{1/4}, \eta_3)/\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, galois-theory

Suppose that $\eta_3$ is a primitive third root of unity and consider the extension of fields $\mathbb{Q}(3^{1/4}, \eta_3)/\mathbb{Q}$. I'd like to compute the Galois Group $\mbox{Aut}_\mathbb{Q} \,\mathbb{Q}(3^{1/4}, \eta_3)$ (where $3^{1/4} \in \mathbb{R}$) and its intermediate fields. I'm familiar with how to do this with splitting fields for polynomials, but I'm not sure how to approach this particular problem.

Comment: I dont think this is a galois extension, it doesnt contain the conjugate $i\sqrt[4]{3}$

Comment: Can't we still determine the isomorphism class of the given Galois Group?

Comment: You can still take the automorphism group, but dont call it a Galois group. However the theory no longer works, you dont get a correspondence between subgroups and subfields.

Comment: Since any automorphism in this group must map $3^{1/4} \mapsto \pm 3^{1/4}$ and $\eta_3 \mapsto z_3$ where $z_3$ is a third root of unity, then the size of this group is 6, correct?

Comment: @RJM How do we get the square roots of -3 from the primitive cube roots of 1?

Answer (score 0):

According to RJM's remark above the field is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3},i)$ now

$$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3},i)/\mathbb{Q}(i)$$ is Galois with automorphism $$\tau(\sqrt[4]{3})=i\sqrt[4]{3}$$

And $$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3},i)/\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3})$$ is also Galois with automorphism $$\sigma(i)=-i$$ It is easy to calculate that $\sigma$ and $\tau$ do not commute. In fact you can find the relation
$$\sigma\tau\sigma=\tau^3$$. This identifies the group as the dihedral group $D_8$.